# Detecting errors in prepared statements

Tags: php

I had a quick question with regard to prepared statements within PHP.  I was previously using the mysql_query function to manipulate database data, but was told that for security issues I should consider using prepared statements.  I have made the transition, but I have a few questions on how to detect whether a query has failed.

Below I have a piece of example code.  The $con variable is a connection which is specific depending on the query I am attempting, in this case the connection would be to my database through an account with only select permissions.

```
$stmt = $con->stmt_init();
$stmt->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users WHERE username=?");
$stmt->bind_param('s', $username);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($user_count);
$stmt->fetch();
$stmt->close();
```

I was wondering how one can detect failure within any of these steps?  The most simple solution I can imagine would be simply to wrap the code using a try/catch.. but I was wondering if there is a more sophisticated way of doing this.

Thanks for reading my question.

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To expand on Jared's comment, you could do the following:

```
$stmt->execute();
if( !$stmt->errorCode() ){
    // do something with results
}else{
    // do something with the error
}
$stmt->close();
```

Comment: `empty` does not work on function calls. Do you want `!$stmt->errorCode()`?